# How to initialize useState variable in react js when embedding Power BI report

Tags: reactjs, powerbi-embedded

I am trying to embed power bi report in react js component using `powerbi-client-react` library. The issue I am facing is with rendering power bi report when `useState` variable is passed or initialized with certain value. In that case the report displays fine but if initialized variables without any values (i.e. empty string) report does not render. Looking for some guidelines here.

I have two react components. A and B for example. From component A I am passing few values to component B which has `<PowerBIEmbed />` to display the report.

I suspect that I am not completely aware how to use these `useState` and `useEffect` hooks efficiently.

In below code if I set the useState hooks variable for reportId and embedUrl in component A, then report loads without issue.

**Code for component A:**

```jsx
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";
import { componentB } from "./componentB";

const componentA = () => {
  const { state } = useLocation();
  let Id = state.id;
  let Value = state.data;

  /* Above values are coming from other parent component */

  const location = useLocation();
  const [details, setDetails] = useState([]);
  const [reportId, setReportId] = useState("");
  const [embedUrl, setEmbedUrl] = useState("");

  /*if this variable is initialized with reportId instead of empty string, report loads perfectly 
      without issue, but that is not the case*/

  let customerId = location.state.customerId;

  useEffect(() => {
    const getUrl = "http://localhost:8080/Api/GetData/" + customerId;
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get(getUrl);
        const data = await response.data;
        setDetails(data);
        url = new URL(data.visualizationUrl);
        const queryParam = new URLSearchParams(url.search);
        setReportId(queryParam.get("reportId"));
        setEmbedUrl(url.href);
      } catch (e) {
        console.log("error", e);
      }
    };
    fetchData();
  }, [customerId]);

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <p>details.customerName</p>
        <p>details.customerAddress</p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <componentB reportId={reportId} embedUrl={embedUrl} />
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default componentA;
```

**Code for component B:**

```jsx
import React from "react";
import { PowerBIEmbed } from "powerbi-client-react";
import { models } from "powerbi-client";

const componentB = (props) => {
  const reportId = props.reportId;
  console.log("report id:", reportId);

  const embedUrl = props.embedUrl;
  console.log("embed url:", embedUrl);

  return (
    <div>
      <PowerBIEmbed
        embedConfig={{
          type: "report",
          id: reportId,
          embedUrl: embedUrl,
          accessToken: "long string of power bi access token",
          tokenType: models.TokenType.Aad, // Use models.TokenType.Aad for SaaS embed
          settings: {
            panes: {
              filters: {
                expanded: false,
                visible: false,
              },
            },
            background: models.BackgroundType.Transparent,
          },
        }}
        eventHandlers={
          new Map([
            [
              "loaded",
              function () {
                console.log("Report loaded");
              },
            ],
            [
              "rendered",
              function () {
                console.log("Report id: ", reportId);
              },
            ],
            [
              "error",
              function (event) {
                console.log(event.detail);
              },
            ],
            ["visualClicked", () => console.log("visual clicked")],
            ["pageChanged", (event) => console.log(event)],
          ])
        }
        cssClassName={"reportClass"}
        getEmbeddedComponent={(embeddedReport) => {
          window.report = embeddedReport;
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default componentB;
```

Comment: If there is any insights around functionality be provided, I much appreciate it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few issues here...

1. `componentB` is the default export but you're trying to import it as named
2. React enforces component names to be PascalCased
3. You don't have anything telling `PowerBIEmbed` or `componentB` to re-render when new data arrives
4. There's no need to `await response.data`

My advice is

1. Rename `componentB` to `ComponentB`
2. Import the default export

   ```js
   import ComponentB from './componentB';
   ```
3. Either use a `key` prop to ensure `ComponentB` re-renders with the new data

   ```html
   <ComponentB key={reportId} reportId={reportId} embedUrl={embedUrl} />
   ```

   or use conditional rendering which would avoid trying to embed empty PowerBI data

   ```jsx
   {
     reportId ? (
       <ComponentB reportId={reportId} embedUrl={embedUrl} />
     ) : (
       <p>Loading...</p>
     );
   }
   ```

Comment: Hi @Phil, tour answer is helpful. Thanks for that. I am moving further in my implementation similar above. Not sure I can update my same question. The way I read reported and embed url, I also need to read access token which is good long string.i am trying similar implementation, but somehow it's not being read when I pass it in variable but if I pass in plain string the report is rendered. Should I ask this as a new question?

Comment: Yes, that sounds like it should be a separate question